# Text indent calculated with js is wrong on Blackberry - how to debug?

Tags: blackberry

I need to center text in a select list cross device and browser. This can't be done with text-align center, so instead ive used javascript to calculate the required text indent value and apply it. This fiddle shows everything working fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnu6D/8/

I cant put my actual code online. It works fine for desktop browsers, iPhone, iPad and Android, but the Blackberry it looks like the text isn't indented enough. I cant work out why this is happening and without firebug type tools ive no idea how to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was a weird one. When I unhid the span thats used to put the text into to be measured I can see its the correct font size. However setting the font size again made the js calculation work.